# Adding a specific nearby places on android

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to filter a nearby place (motorcycle shops). I'm using Google Places API for Android and Maps SDK. I already implemented google maps using the google map activity and also put a find button to my xml activity. Where should I start?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.